# Como suavizar uma curva e definir ylim para uma dada função usando ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cursor

Consegui o seguinte gráfico com a função curve:

```
f1 <- function(x){x^4 - 6*(x^2)}
curve(f1, xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim= c(-10, 5), ylab = expression(x^4 - 6*(x^2)))
```

No entanto, gostaria de usar o pacote ggplot2 para reproduzir este mesmo gráfico (com os mesmos limites de x e y).
Consegui desenvolver este simples código:

```
x <- c(-4:4)
y <- c(x^4 - 6*(x^2))
ggplot() +
   geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Mas, precisaria de suavizar a curva e estabelecer os limites de x e y. Como posso obter um gráfico semelhante ao primeiro utilizando o ggplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você vai usar o `stat_function()` para a função e `ylim()` e `xlim()` para definir os limites:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(-4:4)
f1 <- function(x){x^4 - 6*(x^2)}
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=f1) + ylim(-10, 5) + xlim(-3, 3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está um código exemplo:

```
x = seq(from=-4, to=4, length.out=1000)
y = c(x^4 - 6*(x^2))
print(ggplot(data=data.frame(x=x, y=y), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point(colour='red') +
      stat_smooth(se=F, colour='blue') +
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(-10, 5)))
```

Ou com uma lenda:

```
print(ggplot(data=data.frame(x=x, y=y), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour='source')) +
      stat_smooth(aes(colour='fit'), se=F) +
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(-10, 5)) +
      scale_color_discrete(name='type'))
```